# POST/PUT with html special characters and cyrillic

Tags: python, wordpress, post, encoding, woocommerce

I'm trying to create Python Script for updating products in my Woo-commerce store. Docs suggest using curl:

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/wc-api/v2/products/546 \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
  "product": {
    "regular_price": "24.54"
  }
}'
```

Since I'm working with python, I'm using requests:

## creating product characteristics:

```
new={}
new['id']=555
new['regular_price'] = 1000
new['variations']=[]
new['attributes']=[{'name':'varatt1','variation':True,'options':['opt1','opt2']},{'name':'varatt2','variation':True,'options':['opt11','opt22']}]
new['type']='variable'
var1={}
var1['id']='111'
var1['attributes']=[{'name':'varatt1','option':'opt1'},{'name':'varatt2','option':'opt11'}]
new['variations'].append(var1)
```

## json 'new' and send it via post:

```
f=json.dumps({'product':new})
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
a=requests.put('http://endpoint?authstuff = done, data = f, headers = header)
```

Problem

Everything works fine with pure Latin characters, yet if I'm trying to use Cyrillic names for variations the results are unpredictable - sometimes it works fine, sometimes data partially lost. The second problem is if i try to send, say, description with all those tags - they also get completely lost.

I understand that the problem here is with encoding, yet my experiments with base64 gave me nothing. Also tried using unquote on all Cyrillic strings - with no results. Related questions: is it possible to scrap all this api thing and simply edit Woo-commerce database directly?

Comment: Add Content-Encoding header?

Comment: Tried utf-8, didn't help, or maybe you meant encoding with chunks and stuff?

ALSO! Experimented a bit. I actually can create russian-named variations, yet options should be latin. Or simmetrically - create latin-named variations with russian options - but not simultaneously